# if Spider error processing keep going the script

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am building a web crawler with Scrapy and I want it to be as reliable as possible. The spiders I have are crawling a bunch of differents pages and encouters many exception (layout, data...). When it does encouter an exception, it says "Spider error processing" and stop right away. I want it to still keep going and store the data it managed to get, something like:

```
try:
    description_aem = response.xpath("//div[@class='field-item odd']/p/text()").extract()[0]
except ValueError:
    description_aem = 'erreur'
```

Then it would store the data it manage to get, and for the data that raise any kind of error it would store 'error' so i can manually enter the data i want afterward.

Comment: Can’t you just surround the callback with a `try: … except Exception: …` to do that?

Comment: @Gallaecio yo it seems to work like a charm! many thanks :) have a nice one <3